# gaining root user permission on an android device programatically in java in order to change scaling_governor

Tags: android, cpu, root, frequency

I'm trying to develop an android application in which I'm trying to change the scaling_governor to userspace so that I can set the cpu frequency, but I don't know how to gain root user permission programatically in order to change the scaling_governor. Is there any way to change the scaling_governor and to set user specified cpu frequency?

Comment: If you don't know how to gain root permissions, you probably shouldn't be messing with the CPU frequency

Answer (score 1):

To gain super-user privileges, you have to use Unix commands in a shell, something like this:

`Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");`

Then use the process input/output to send commands, read output.